# Eclipse with GWT plug-in: unable to download for Chrome/Firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, firefox, gwt

So, I'm trying to set up a project using GWT with Eclipse Mars.2, I'm following the intructions in the [GWT Eclipse config page](http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html), but when it comes time to run in development mode, my browser says it doesn't have the GWT Developer Plugin. Problem arises when I try to install it, as Firefox only has support for this plugin until FF26(and I'm on 47), and Chrome has no support for NPAPI plugins anymore, and so I can't download this plugin from the google store.

I don't really know how to go on from here, is there another way to install the GWT plugin, or is there an alternative for it? Thanks.

Comment: nope no other way available, you should either download ff26 to use classic dev mode or start use of [super dev mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

devmode has been deprecated for quite a while now, and GWT 2.7's DevMode defaults to using superdevmode. devmode will actually be removed entirely after GWT 2.8.

SuperDevMode can be used starting with GWT  2.5 but is really usable only from GWT 2.7, where it's also easier to use (just refresh the page, like in legacy devmode).

So, you should upgrade to GWT 2.7 if you haven't already, and use SuperDevMode from now on.

Comment: This is really the correct solution.

Please note that the GWT website is outdated on this devmode/superdevmode thing and really needs updating on this.

I hope I can find some time in the near future to look into this myself.